# Is it a good idea to apply for companies with job ads constantly active?

Tags: job-search, job-description

I was casually browsing available jobs when I saw an interesting job ad for a senior position from a startup which has recently raised Series A funding. When I first saw the ad, the timestamp on it said it had been posted 4 months ago, but when I look at it now it seems it has been renewed/reposted, since I can see it's only 1 week old.

To my surprise, through the app that I use to look for jobs, I could see that I had actually applied exactly for the same ad (same company, position, description, and salary range) about a year ago when I was looking for a new job.

So, it seems there is a good chance that this job ad is constantly on. I know it can be hard to find the right candidate, but it seems weird that a job ad would stay on for more than a year. The other reason I can think of, is high turnover, so they found a new person which has already left, and they have reposted exactly the same job ad.

In short, am I right to see red flags for this particular set of circumstances?

Comment: No. You are not right to see red flags.

Comment: Up until recently, my employer was continually looking for new employees. For software developers, usually only *after* hiring would the decision be made in which team the new employee would actually land. I'm sure that if they advertise, they will renew or reuse ads, because that is more efficient than just creating new ones every time (especially given we couldn't hire fast enough to account for growth *and* attrition, we also hired a lot of contractors and freelancers).

Answer (score 2):

No, it not a red flag by itself, but you're right to dig a little deeper as to why. Some thoughts about previous employers of mine who did that:

- they tended to place importance on getting really good fits, and would wait for a great candidate, rather than filling a vacancy with the best of a cohort of applicants.
- their budgets were flexible enough that they could create an extra place for a great candidate, if one applied, rather than turn them away.
- they were large enough, and had fungible-enough roles, that even with normal levels of attrition there would likely be a place for someone in the not too distant future.

Alternatively, it could be a highly specialist role where there are very few candidates.

However, as you've applied previously, and presumably were unsuccessful, prospects are not that good at a company like one of the above unless you've grown somewhat since the previous time. No harm in applying, but prepare a couple of questions to better understand their position if you get to talk to them.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons job ads may keep recurring, not all of them have anything at all to do with the job.

It can be a part of a marketing/company strategy. Having jobs on offer make it look like a strong and expanding company in combination with other things. This is particularly prevalent with start ups looking for funding. There may be no job available at all, but they practice interviewing and network.

There's a local company here thats had the same few job ads up for over a decade. Hundreds including myself have applied over the years, but there is no actual job opening.

It can even be as simple as they paid for an ad and then forgot it. So it just gets billed and put up again periodically, these things can slip through.